# Why do I get "Undefined variable" errors with pseudo-selectors in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

The following is perfectly valid CSS:

```
#someID::before {
   --var: 1px;
}

.someClass #someID::before {
   # use --var in here
}
```

But when I try to do the same thing in SASS, I get an undefined variable error:

```
#someID::before {
   $var: 1px;
}

.someClass #someID::before {
   # use $var in here
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how scoping works in SASS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS variables ([CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)) and SCSS variables are not the same. SCSS variables are for values. For example, let's say I have a brand guideline and I use the colours like this:

```css
$black: #000;
$white: #fff;
```

And now I can use this way:

```css
header {
  .topbar {
    background: $white;
  }
}
```

But CSS variables are similar. And also, you are declaring the variable in the global scope there.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. So It's like preprocessor directives that get plugged into the code exactly as they appear, and are not treated as variables. Thanks for clearing that up! It looks like I should really be using custom properties in this case.

Comment: @AlexH No, you should be using SCSS Variables in this case, and it helps you to maintain different stuff like theming and configuration, for example. And you can declare the SCSS variables in the global scope. See [Sass: Variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) for more information. Also give a shout, if you need to know more. Happy to help you.

Comment: @AlexH Updated the above comment. ^

Comment: Hmm, I see. The reason I don't want to declare the SCSS variables in the global scope is because I'm going to be importing the stylesheet into another one. My understanding is that those variables would then leak into the global scope of the final stylesheet, correct?

Comment: @AlexH All the SCSS variables are global scope by nature. You can, anyway, replace the file imports, whether you wanna import the variables from `file1.scss` or `file2.scss` conditionally. 

Comment: Actually, I think I may really need to use custom properties. I should clarify, since my original post was a bit vague. the `.someClass` is going to get toggled at runtime via a click. Per this article, it seems SCSS variables are really static: https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/

Comment: @AlexH So even though global, it won't affect your scope. You can also scope your variables by appending some prefix to each. I know it's tough but yea, it's doable.

Comment: @AlexH Yes, [What is the difference between CSS variables and preprocessor variables?](https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/) is a great article to follow. I guess with what you said, it's better you go with CSS Custom Properties and not SCSS Variables. Let me know if you need any help! 